# different data type using dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, swift

I just learned about NSURLSession. I want to make POST request. it needs JSON as the body.

when using Objective-C I used NSDictionary, but in swift I Dictionary only hold 1 data type. what is the alternative to implement this in swift?

```
{
    "userID" : "xxxxxxxx",
    "full_name" : "xxxxxxxxx",
    "pob" : "xxxxxxxxxx"
    "dob" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "status" : 3,
    "phone_number" : null,
    "education" : [
        {
            "university" : "xxxxxx",
            "location": {
                latitude: "xxxxxxx",
                longitude: "xxxxxxxx"
             },
             "degree": "xxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "university" : "xxxxxx",
            "location": {
                latitude: "xxxxxxx",
                longitude: "xxxxxxxx"
             },
             "degree": "xxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

i'm really stuck, I've looking for the solution for hours but no luck. haven't found any tutorial about this in google.

thank you very much, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Dictionary<Any, Any>`, it's like NSDictionary

Comment: I can't use Any as the key, it shows an error "Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'"

Comment: No need to use Any as the key.  It's always a string.

Comment: Do as @HotLicks suggested. Or you can use `Dictionary<Hashable, Any>`

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `NSDictionary`:

```
var dictionary: NSDictionary = [
    "userID" : "xxxxxxxx",
    "full_name" : "xxxxxxxxx",
    "pob" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "dob" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "status" : 3,
    "phone_number" : NSNull(),
    "education" : [
        [
            "university" : "xxxxxx",
            "location": [
                "latitude" : "xxxxxxx",
                "longitude" : "xxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "degree": "xxxxxx"
        ],
        [
            "university" : "xxxxxx",
            "location": [
                "latitude": "xxxxxxx",
                "longitude": "xxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "degree": "xxxxxx"
        ]
    ]
]
```

For easy working with JSON responses you can use libraries like:

- https://github.com/owensd/json-swift
- https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: **I would discourage the use of old Obj-C-only classes**. Anyway, +1 for libraries.

Comment: Agreed, but while there is no built in alternative for `NSJSONSerialization` I guess there is still use for `NSDictonary`.

Comment: When used in swift, Obj-C methods that return an `NSDictionary`, return a Swift's `Dictionary<Any, Any>`. Same is for methods that return an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>
dictionary["userID"] = "xxxxxxxx"
dictionary["status"] = 200
like that ...
```

Comment: I tried it.

NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: nil, error: nil)

it's error "Type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'